# GMP's mpf division with a 0 result

Tags: c, visual-c++, gnu, gmp

When using GMP lib,I get a all-0 result like that in the image after using GMP C function mpf_div(),[all-0 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMWhF.jpg).I have already put a line of codes to set the default precision but you can see,only the first result is correct and the rest are not wanted.So is there anyting special I need to do when using the division function?The lib's version is 6.2.1 and the compiler is MSVC 143.Great thanks to your help.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

printf("%.numFf",mpf_t);This works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).